# Can I stroke a path with a color and a different colored border?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, cgcontext

Is it possible to stroke a path so that the stroke line has a different colored border?  The same effect could be achieved by stroking the path black with a line width of 5, and then drawing the same path over it stroking it white with a line width of 3, so that the line would be black with a thin white line on either side.  I'd rather not use this approach though because I'm drawing tons of polylines already and don't want to slow things down unnecessarily.  I'm hoping it can be done with patterns or something.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: Use `CGContextReplacePathWithStrokedPath` to replace your path with a path outline. Then you could fill and stroke the new path with different colors.

Comment: Good idea and I didn't even know about that function. However, after experimenting with it, it doesn't quite work out.  It does allow me to have something to fill as well as stroke, but the stroke is drawn on top of the fill, and in the corners it has weird little loops that don't look good. I did it by duplicating the path with CGPathCreateCopy though this also isn't perfect for my application because when lines intersect, the border intersects too, rather than treating the inner line like a polygon and stroking only the outside edges (if that makes sense). Still, it seems like the way to go.

Comment: @RyanQuick: It was just an idea ... If you stroke first and fill afterwards then I assume that the fill is "on top". But I can imagine that corners and intersecting lines are a problem!